# Function returning T<A> doesn't compile in certain typedef situation

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I don't understand why `func3()` can't compile, when `func2()` and `func4()` do.

- [g++ 4.1.2](http://codepad.org/about): `error: 'B<T>::my_t' has incomplete type`
- VS2008: `error C2079: 'B<T>::my_t' uses undefined class 'A'`

---

```
template <typename T>
struct C {
    T mt_t;
};

template <typename T>
struct B {
    typedef C<T> C_type;
    T my_t;
};

struct Other {};

struct A {
    B<A>             func2();
    B<A>::C_type     func3(); // error: 'B<T>::my_t' has incomplete type
    B<Other>::C_type func4();
};

int main() {}
```

Comment: It was not edited by Stack Overflow. It was edited by me. If somebody wants to find out the old title for some reason, then they can look at the revision history.

Comment: @Dima: That's only valid when the surrounding context is a template. `func3` is not a template. The issue [is not the function body](http://codepad.org/mDbs49lj), but the function signature [and `typename` is not valid there](http://codepad.org/CeILzboY).

Comment: Terser testcase: http://codepad.org/hIMT6czH

Comment: The function calls are unnecessary complications here. The simple use of `typedef` demonstrates the problem: `typedef B<A> BA;` is ok, can be used in the context where complete type is not requred, but using qualified-id `typedef B<A>::Anything BAny;` triggers implicit instantiation, even if *theoretically* it can be resolved by lookup.

Comment: @Gene: The function _declarations_ (not calls) are very much relevant, as the OP was wondering why only some worked and others didn't.

Answer (score 3):

Well, when you try to get `B<A>::C_type`, you have to instantiate `template <typename> B`, but you cannot instantiate the template on an incomplete type because it contains a member object `T my_t` which mustn't be incomplete -- the compiler doesn't know that you only want to get at the member typedef of `B<A>`.

In `func2`, you only use `B<A>` as a return type, which is allowed to be incomplete -- we don't need to instantiate `B<A>` in order to allow it as a return type. But to access the member (typedef) we *do* need to instantiate `B<A>`. Furhtermore, `func4` is fine because `Other` is a complete type.

The solution is simple, just resolve the typedef by hand and make the return type of `func3` into `C<A>`.

Comment: "we don't need to instantiate B<A> in order to allow it as a return type." I was wondering about this. Why not?

Comment: @Tomalak: Wasn't it you who pointed this very thing out to me a few days ago? Incomplete types can be used for return types and function parameters... I suppose because member functions don't occupy any space inside the class data structure.

Comment: It wasn't me, but [it seems that you're right](http://codepad.org/UJkW3Khp). Then this is the answer.

Comment: @Tomalak: For the same reason this works: `struct D; D func1(D);`. The compiler doesn't need to know about the innards of `B<A>` (or of `struct D`) here. It just needs to know that `B<A>` (or `D`) is a valid type name.

Comment: Haha, proof by compilation :-) The underlying reason might be worth considering, though: The only time you need a *complete* type is when you either access its members, or when you need to be able to lay out a type in memory. So I suppose function declaration don't require either of those, and neither do pointers or references.

Comment: @Kerrek: My answer provides proof by citation :D

Comment: @Tomalak: I hadn't noticed the new answer -- +1!

Comment: now we just need to find a clause in the Standard that tells that qualified-id in this case causes template instantiation.

Comment: @Kerrek: Well I only just posted it ;)

Comment: @Kerrek -- as the original example demonstrates, you don't *theoretically* need a complete type to use a qualified-id, but it's probably required by standard (unless all compilers are wrong :-)

Comment: @Gene: It's more complicated than that. There are different scenarios.

Comment: @Tomalak: don't hide from us complications and different scenarios :-)

Comment: The implicit instantiation is described in section 14.7.1 of the standard. The requirements are kind of fuzzy, it basically says the the template is instantiated if the *context requires a completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program.* One can argue whether context requires it in this case.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few factors at play here.

---

### `A` is incomplete

First, in all the function declarations:

```
B<A>             func2();
B<A>::C_type     func3();
B<Other>::C_type func4();
```

`A` is an incomplete type:

> `[2003: 9.2/2]:` A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or
>   complete type) at the closing `}` of the *class-specifier*. Within the
>   class *member-specification*, the class is regarded as complete within
>   function bodies, default arguments, and constructor ctor-initializers (including such things in nested classes). **Otherwise it is regarded as
>   incomplete within its own class *member-specification*.**

---

### `B<A>` needs to be instantiated

#### `func2` and `func4` are OK

Second, the function return type *may* be incomplete. That means that the return types of `func2` and `func4` are fine just the way they are.

> `[2003: 8.3.5/6]:` [..] The type of a parameter or the return type for
>   a function definition shall not be an incomplete class type (possibly
>   cv-qualified) unless the function definition is nested within the
>   *member-specification* for that class (including definitions in nested
>   classes defined within the class).

#### `func3` is not OK

However, in the more complex example of `func3`, in order to use the type `B<A>::C_type`, `B<A>` must be complete.*

And so it must also be *instantiated*:

> `[2003: 14.7.1/1]:` Unless a class template specialization has been
>   explicitly instantiated (14.7.2) or explicitly specialized (14.7.3),
>   **the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the
>   specialization is referenced in a context that requires a
>   completely-defined object type** or when the completeness of the class
>   type affects the semantics of the program. [..]

But, because `B<A>` contains a member of type `A`, and `A` is not a complete type, and `[8.3.5/6]` requires it to be, the instantiation is invalid, `B<A>` remains incomplete... and the program is ill-formed.

---

<sup>* I haven't yet found a citation to back this up, though it seems obvious.</sup>

Comment: There is a gap in logical argument, namely the very last sentence. Because it's not *required* (in absolute sense) to instantiate a template to know what the typedef is. The example can even be simplified to `typedef int C_type;` with the same results.

Comment: @Gene: You're right in that there's a gap here. However, I can't find a citation proving that using the scope resolution operator in `x::y` requires `x` to be complete if it's a class type, though it seems obvious. I think that it might not be explicitly stated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the relevant paragraph comes from the classes chapter 2:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or
>   complete type) at the closing } of the class-specifier. Within the
>   class member-specification, the class is regarded as complete within
>   function bodies, default arguments, exception-specifications, and
>   brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members (including
>   such things in nested classes). Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete
>   within its own class member-specification.

```
B<A> func2()  //A is incomplete here, but B<A> isn't instantiated
{
    return B<A>();  //A is complete here
}

B<A>::C_type func3() //A is incomplete, B<A> needs to be instantiated for C_type
{
    return B<A>::C_type(); //OK, A is complete
}
```

Comment: the question is not why the `class A` is incomplete, the question is why `typedef` makes the difference difference.

Comment: @Gene: It's not about the `typedef`. It's about using a member of `B<A>`.

Comment: @Tomalak -- which is `typedef` in this question, or am I missing something else?

Comment: @Gene: I'm saying that `typedef` _specifically_ isn't all that related. Yes, it happens to be part of this particular scenario.

Comment: @Gene: The asker might be surprised that the compiler says A is incomplete. Then it might help to realize that a class is incomplete (with listed exceptions) within the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

**It is a circular reference:**

In order for the compiler to understand what the structure `A` is, it must be able to understand what `B<A>::C_type` (since it contains a member that returns an object of this type). So, in order to understand what `B<A>::C_type` is, the compiler must understand what `B<A>` is. But in order to understand what `B<A>` is, the compiler needs to know what `A` is.

Essentially, you've given the compiler a paradox: in order to understand what `A` is, you need to first know what `A` is.

Answer (score -1):

You can store the member `my_t` in `template <typename T> struct B` as pointer and handle its construction, destruction and copying in `struct B`, like so:

```
template <typename T>
struct B
{
    typedef C<T> C_type;
    T* my_t;
};
```

Comment: Thus vastly complicating your code. And this answer doesn't explain anything.